# Concat own column to parent column recursively in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression, recursive-query

My goal is to create a unique ID based on the Location of each record. Below I have my Source table, expected output and what I already tried.

This is my Source table.

| ID | Location | Name | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Room 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | Table 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Table 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | Chair 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | Chair 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 9 | Room 2 | NULL |
| 7 | 1 | Chair 3 | 3 |

My goal is to get an output like this:

| ID | Location | Name | ParentID | ConcatLocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Room 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Table 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | Table 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 4 | 1 | Chair 1 | 2 | 111 |
| 5 | 2 | Chair 2 | 2 | 112 |
| 6 | 9 | Room 2 | NULL | 9 |
| 7 | 1 | Chair 3 | 3 | 121 |

I've tried https://kimsereylam.com/sqlite/2020/03/13/recursive-query-in-sqlite-with-cte.html but this does not give me the result I want. This was the code I made from that website:

```
with recursive
    child_record(ID, Name, ParentID, Location, NewLocation) as (
        select S.ID, S.Name, S.ParentID, S.Location, S.Location
        from Source S
        
        UNION
        
        select S.ID, S.Name, S.ParentID, S.Location, S.Location, c.Location || S.Location
        from Source S, child_record c
        where c.ID = S.ParentID
    )
select * from child_record
```

This however returns me a table with the initial 7 records, followed by 5 records which only concatenated their first parent instead of going to the Parent with ParentID NULL.

| ID | Location | Name | ParentID | NewLocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Room 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Table 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Table 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | Chair 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | Chair 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 9 | Room 2 | NULL | 9 |
| 7 | 1 | Table 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Table 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | Table 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 4 | 1 | Chair 1 | 2 | 11 |
| 5 | 2 | Chair 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 7 | 1 | Chair 3 | 3 | 21 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the rows that have `NULL` as `ParentID` and then join the children:

```
WITH cte(ID, Name, ParentID, Location, ConcatLocation) AS (
  SELECT ID, Location, Name, ParentID, Location
  FROM Source 
  WHERE ParentID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT S.ID, S.Location, S.Name, S.ParentID, c.ConcatLocation || S.Location
  FROM Source S INNER JOIN cte c
  ON c.ID = S.ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=845fa37e70a941d33688da678dd9d510).
Results:

| ID | Location | Name | ParentID | ConcatLocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Room 1 | null | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Table 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | Table 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 4 | 1 | Chair 1 | 2 | 111 |
| 5 | 2 | Chair 2 | 2 | 112 |
| 6 | 9 | Room 2 | null | 9 |
| 7 | 1 | Chair 3 | 3 | 121 |

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm. Only thing in your example is that you switched some columns but rearranging them I indeed got the result I want.